# How to update the kernel for a live CD Linux image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, livecd

I have a liveCD ubuntu Linux iso image. I need to update the kernel of this image. I've tried to get the iso on a host Ubuntu system and move the compiled kernel and the modules from there to the liveCD but after doing that, the system stuck at:

loading kernel /casper/vmlinuz.. done
loading file /casper/inited.img.. done

I think that the initrd can't find the root filesystem which is at "/casper/filesyste.squashfs".

Does anyone know a valid way to do this task? my next attempt would be to mount the root filesystem of liveCD on the host system and compile the new kernel from there.

Comment: I'd honestly just go through the process that Ubuntu uses to create their liveCDs! That seems to most clean.

Comment: In case you only need a portable system, you could also install Ubuntu onto a USB thumb drive. You can install any supported kernel in a convenient manner. Not an option if you absolutely need a read-only boot medium of course.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What's the process? can u provide link, please. Thanks

Comment: @Hermann The thing is that I already have a customized image and want to update its kernel because some devices such as network interface card on modern hardware doesn't work.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Live_CD_Kernel

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I'm already using this link. It works fine if I want to modify anything in the filesystem itself, but when I tried to replace the kernel, initrd and add the kernel modules, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by:

Installing the new kernel in the chroot environment of the liveCD root file system itself and then moved the new kernel (vmlinuz) and the initramfs image (initrd) to the /casper directory in the USB top filesystem.

Comment: This can't possibly be the complete solution. Starting with at least 18.04 Live CD ISO's require GPG signing, without which (as far as  can tell) they won't boot.